# Combine perspective and ortho

Tags: 3d-view, camera, orthographic

I know it may sound weird or impossible, but can I somehow combine perspective view with orthogonal?

Example: all body of the character in perspective and head only in ortho.

I know about the sensor size value, auto, vertical, horizontal fitting, but it can't give that result.

Or maybe, at least, I can scale head alone to make an illusion of orthographic view?

Comment: Could you please post some reference image or at least tell us why you need something like this? First impression is that this is not possible, but maybe with some better explanation (with example) we could help you.

Comment: Sure.
Right now I'm experimenting with 3D->2D techniques and want to make perspective still look 2d, that's why.
Here's an example (I do not own model): 
[1](https://pp.userapi.com/c841139/v841139504/3a5bd/kOdb6VVNXPQ.jpg),[2](https://pp.userapi.com/c841139/v841139504/3a5c6/DQLP_nxDGOQ.jpg)
As you can see, face on second image still looks a little bit 3d, it's noticeable. And on first all is ok except lack of perspective.
To conclude, I want to save perspective look for body from the second image and add an ortho head view from first.

Comment: I think this will help you: http://blendernpr.org/ check tutorials and download section.

Comment: This source is really useful for many occasions, but there's nothing what I'm asking about on this site.

Comment: You would have to render with 2 different cameras in the same scene. Not sure if you can make one an ortho while the other is regular. Also they would have to be setup on seperate layers and comped together in the compositor or VSE

Comment: I'm afraid it would be a mess, if I just combine 2 layers with alpha. But... Maybe I can hide/mask some faces during render, so I can really use compositor and alpha layers and get what I want?